# How do I merge branch 2 with branch 1 in my case below?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

using gitk --all my branches looks as following... (* means commits)

```
b0........ ...*...*...
          |          |
          |          |
         b1         b2
                     |
                     |
                    b2.1
```

but what I want it to look like

```
b1........ ...*...*....merge b1&(mergeb2&b2.1)
          |            |
          |            |
         b2 -------merge b2&b2.1        |
          |            |
          |            |
          |..........b2.1
```

what I'm try to say, is that I want the first branch to to have my latest feature in branch 2.

Answer (score -1):

you can try go to the branch1 and pull the code of branch2 and branch 2.1, then you push the code to server

```
git checkout branch1
git pull origin branch2
git pull origin branch2.1
git push
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question?